# List box ItemTemplateSelector not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one ListBox with ItemTemplateSelector.
My TemplateSelector is selcting the correct Template but not showing anything on UI.

If i do the same process with ItemsControl things are working perfectly fine. But, as i want the selctedItem property i want to use ListBox.

My XAML Code : -

```
<ListBox x:Name="CanvasItemsControl" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemListViewModel.CanvasItems}">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <Canvas/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Please suggest if the implementation for ItemTemplateSelector is not correct in my code.

Comment: "Please suggest if the implementation for ItemTemplateSelector is not correct in my code". Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

First define your templates in resource, then in your code file define the DataTemplateSelector

```
public class templateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private DataTemplate _Template1;
    public DataTemplate Template1
    {
        get { return _Template1; }
        set { _Template1 = value; }
    }


    private DataTemplate _Template2;
    public DataTemplate Template2
    {
        get { return _Template2; }
        set { _Template2 = value; }
    }


    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        YourClass obj = (YourClass)item;

        if (obj.Type == "SomeType")
        {
            return Template1;
        }
        else
        {
            return Template2;
        }
    }

}

<ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <local:FieldRangeTemplateSelector 
        Template1="{StaticResource YouyTemplate1}"
        Template2="{StaticResource YoutTemplate2}" />
</ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
```